# Viewport 100% height is not div 100% height, why?

Tags: css, height

here is the page : http://benoitjacquesdesigner.com/intro_fra1.php

On this page, on FF mac, the menu at the left extend ALL THE WAY down to the bottom (if screen is 1000x715), everything scroll... i am happy

On PC, it's only 100% height of view-port, or not 100% of the height of the div. I like to know what to add to my css to FIX this permanently. I want 100% #menu height of the #wrapper

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `100%` for me of the `#wrapper` div and not the viewport, am using Firefox 15.1 on `Windows`, which version are you talking anout? And btw a suggestion, you are using `html5` so always use this..

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

And I also saw this

```
#menu {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

So just use 1 of the above, no need to specify both..

Comment: i have try one, both, none.... absolutely no changes, and clear browser cache in between !... no luck ! :-(

Comment: @menardmam Which version are you using because am getting 100% height

Comment: on mac : ff 16. on pc : ie7, ff 10, chrome 22